# Scrolling on an ItemsControl

Tags: xaml, scrollviewer, itemscontrol, windows-phone-8.1

I have created info inside a PivotItem but for some reason the items do not scroll, I've tried scrolling but it creates a sort of compressed effect and not scrolling down.

I have tried wrapping it with a `ScrollViewer` and also tried

```
<ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
            <ItemsPresenter />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ItemsControl.Template>
```

With no luck - can anyone identify what could be wrong?

```
            <PivotItem Header="unread">


                    <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" >

                        <ItemsControl.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="True">
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.Template>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                           // ---


                            </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>

            </PivotItem>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just put the ScrollViewer around the ItemsControl, not inside it. Something like this:

```
<Pivot TabNavigation="Once">
    <PivotItem Header="unread">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
                //Some ItemsControl properties and stuff
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

**Solved**

For everyone reading this - the problem was that the Pivot was in a StackPanel. And ScrollViewers do not work inside of StackPanels, because these panels have unlimited height (or width, depending on the Orientation), and then there's nothing to scroll as everything fits. You could use a StackPanel inside a ScrollViewer, though.

Comment: @SandeepBansal Hmm, well it is working for me. Try it again, and remove the ControlTemplate that you're setting to the ItemsControl. Leave just this one ScrollViewer around the ItemsControl. If that doesn't work, I think we'll need more info about the ItemTemplate and anything else that may be related.

Comment: @SandeepBansal Hmm it looks okay, works for me. That's a bit of a stretch, but what's the PivotItem in? Are there any StackPanels? Canvases? They don't work very well with ScrollViewers.

Comment: Nope the PivotItem is in a Pivot Control. Trying it directly on the emulator doesn't work

Comment: @SandeepBansal Well, you could try to remove the big ItemTemplate and leave just a TextBlock in it and see if it works, but I guess the problem is outside the ItemsControl. In the visual tree, what are the elements between the root of the page and the Pivot? Also, is there any chance that you're changing something through a default style or code?

Comment: Silly me, it turned out there was a StackPanel before the Pivot!! Removed it and all is working. Thanks for the help.